# Dealing with pointer arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to implement a convolution algorithm in C using pointers.

I know my deconvolution.c code is correct. However, I struggle to call the function in Main to get desired results. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 // deconvolution.c
 #include "deconvolution.h"
 #include "math.h"

 void deconvolution (double *Win, double *Vin, int *N, int *j, int *L, double *ht, double *gt, double *Vout)
 {
     int k, n, t;
     for(t = 0; t < *N; t++) {
         k = t;
         Vout[t] = (ht[0] * Win[k]) + (gt[0] * Vin[k]);
         for(n = 1; n < *L; n++) {
            k += (int) pow(2.0, (double) *j - 1.0);
             if(k >= *N) k -= *N;
             Vout[t] += (ht[n] * Win[k]) + (gt[n] * Vin[k]);
         }
     }
  }


  //////////////

 // deconvolution.h
 #include <stdio.h>

 void deconvolution (
                     double *Win, double *Vin, int *N, int *j, int *L, double *ht, double *gt, double *Vout);

  //////////////

 // main.c
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

     int N = 9; // Size of Win and Vin
     int J = 3; // Levels
     int L = 4; // Size of gt and ht

    double *Vout = NULL; // output will be stored here

     double Win = {1.0, -2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, -9.0};
     double Vin = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, -7.0, 8.0, 9.0};
     double ht = {-1.0, 2.0, -3.0, -4.0};
     double gt = {-1.0, 2.0, 3.0, -4.0};

     deconvolution (
               Win, Vin, N, J, L, ht, gt, Vout);

 // Should Print Vout = {40.0, -16.0, -42.0, 24.0, -74.0, -8.0, -8.0, -46.0, -8.0}
 // But I get an error

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Allocate memory which `Vout` will point to. Otherwise you are accessing uninitialized pointer giving you undefined behavior.

Either you allocate memory dynamically using `malloc` or by use array with automatic storage duration big enough to hold the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function prototype has some integer constants declared as pointers

```
void deconvolution (double *Win
                    , double *Vin
                    , int *N
                    , int *j
                    , int *L
                    , double *ht
                    , double *gt
                    , double *Vout)
```

But when you call deconvolution you do not pass the address to these constants

```
deconvolution ( Win, Vin, N, J, L, ht, gt, Vout); // &N,&J,&L
```

You should change deconvolution to normal ints instead, since you
do not change N,J,L in the function there is no reason to
pass the address to them.

```
void deconvolution (double *Win
                    , double *Vin
                    , int N
                    , int j
                    , int L
                    , double *ht
                    , double *gt
                    , double *Vout)
```

`Vout` btw is set to NULL so if you need to write to Vout you will get an error,
you need to allocate memory which can be done inside the function deconvolution
or outside if you already know the size. If you want to allocate `Vout` inside your function you need to change `double* Vout` to `double** Vout` so that you can change what `Vout` points to.

Comment: Thanks so much to all ! The methods suggested by user3247643 & Anders K. both work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Like coderredoc says, Vout is not initialized to memory, it needs to be something like `double *Vout = malloc(N*sizeof(double))`.

But what would be more useful to you is to enable compiler warnings (e.g. in GCC it is done with -Wall). There are many more warnings in this case. I would then fix the warnings.

Then run the program in a debugger (e.g. GDB). The debugger shows you which line crashes and then you look why it crashes: what does that line do/need. In this case the line says `Vout[t] = ...` so you say to yourself "let me check if Vout is a null pointer".

Answer (score 0):

It's not proper code.

First, the function definition is not correct. In main func., you call deconvolution function like "deconvolution (Win, Vin, N, J, L, ht, gt, Vout);.
But, N, J, L is not pointer variable.

If you want to call this form, you should define "void deconvolution (double *Win, double *Vin, **int N, int j, int L**, double *ht, double *gt, double *Vout); Or You should call deconvolution like deconvolution (Win, Vin, &N, &J, &L, ht, gt, Vout);

Next, "double *Vout = NULL;" is not array. It's pointer variable. It means, there is not allocated memory address on Vout. If you want to get proper result, you should write "double Vout[9];".

Finally, Win, Vin, ht, and gt is not well defined. In code, it is arrays. But, in your code it is double type variable. So, you shoul wirte "Win[], Vin[], ht[], gt[]".

you will change below code, you can get well result.

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

```
int N = 9; // Size of Win and Vin
int J = 3; // Levels
int L = 4; // Size of gt and ht

double Vout[9]; // output will be stored here

double Win[] = {1.0, -2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, -9.0};
double Vin[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, -7.0, 8.0, 9.0};
double ht[] = {-1.0, 2.0, -3.0, -4.0};
double gt[] = {-1.0, 2.0, 3.0, -4.0};

deconvolution (Win, Vin, &N, &J, &L, ht, gt, Vout);

// Should Print Vout = {40.0, -16.0, -42.0, 24.0, -74.0, -8.0, -8.0, -46.0, -8.0}
// But I get an error

return 0;
```

}